# What's the purpose of the "Songbird Defense System" statues?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

In Bioshock Infinite, there is a Comstock statue in her room, that starts playing a tune, and makes Elizabeth realize Songbird is coming back-- we also see these statues later in the game, sometimes they play a tune, sometimes they don't.

What are they? Why were they built? What makes them play their tunes? I don't think the game ever fully fleshed this out, unless I missed something..

Answer (score 3):

The tune summons and controls the songbird. This is established near the end.  Why they're all over the island rather than just in Elizabeth's tower- good planning on Comstock's part, I guess?

Comment: Prophets are *always* good planners :)

Comment: @Tacroy Indeed, if they're any good they are! ;)